# Simple Logic Circuit Not Behaving As Expected (TinkerCad)

Tags: digital-logic

[image: Circuit]

I need to build the following cicruit: F = (A AND B) OR (A XOR B) and I came up with the circuit in the image above. The bulb is only turning on when both A and B are OFF. The expected behavior is for the bulb to turn on if (A OR B).

I tested all the gates and bulb seperately and they all work as expected but the switch inputs don't, so I'm thinking it has something to do with the switch.

Comment: Draw the schematic.

Comment: As Andy aka says, you should draw the circuit. If you draw a schematic diagram of the circuit from your wiring diagram, then I think you will see the problem. Trace out your circuit from the wiring diagram, and draw the schematic using individual logic gates rather than pins going into a box.  It would also help us yo help you if you put a copy of the schematic in your question.

Comment: On stack exchange sites, the solution of a problem is indicated not be editing the question, but rather by accepting (if necessary, first providing) a suitable answer.  You have already accepted an answer, so your improper edit of the question has been rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look at your Tinkerc cct.

Inputs to the 7486 XOR gate are both at logic 0 always. They are connected to GND. Output of the XOR will therefore always be 0 too. You need to connect the inputs to the upper side of the slide switch.